# 400 MSG_ID_INVALID for GetMessageReactionsList in Pyrogram

Tags: python, asynchronous, telegram, pyrogram

I wrote a script to collect data using Pyrogram but got the error 400 MSG_ID_INVALID on some messages. I didn't notice a pattern why some messages cause errors and others don't. Maybe the problem is with asynchronous programming.

Chat id and message id are correct because app.get_messages(chat_id, message.id) always works fine.

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.raw.functions.messages import GetMessageReactionsList


# configuration
with open('config.txt', 'r') as f:
    api_id = f.readline().strip()
    api_hash = f.readline().strip()
    chat_id = int(f.readline().strip())


app = Client(
    "my_account",
    api_id=api_id,
    api_hash=api_hash
)


async def collect_messages():
    async with app:

        chat = await app.resolve_peer(peer_id=chat_id)

        async for message in app.get_chat_history(chat_id=chat_id, limit=1):

            message_id = message.id

            # always works fine
            print(await app.get_messages(chat_id, message.id))

            # 400 MSG_ID_INVALID for some messages
            reactions = await app.invoke(GetMessageReactionsList(peer=chat, id=message.id, limit=10))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(collect_messages())
```

Full error:

```
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.MsgIdInvalid: Telegram says: [400 MSG_ID_INVALID] - The message ID used in the peer was invalid (caused by "messages.GetMessageReactionsList")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this error appears when the message doesn't have any reactions. To avoid it you can check that message.reactions is not None:

```
async def collect_messages():
    async with app:

        chat = await app.resolve_peer(peer_id=chat_id)

        async for message in app.get_chat_history(chat_id=chat_id, limit=30):
            message_id = message.id

            # check reactions
            try:
                reactions = await app.invoke(GetMessageReactionsList(peer=chat, id=message.id, limit=10))
                print(reactions)
            except pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.MsgIdInvalid:
                pass
```